# Hybris: Use same field for search and facet

Tags: search, solr, facet, faceted-search, sap-commerce-cloud

I have to use a field "manufacturerName" for both solr search and solr facet in Hybris. While the solr free text search requires the field type to be text, the facet only works properly in string type.

Is there any way to use this same field for both search and facet. I think there is one way by using "copyField" but I searched a lot, and still don't know how to use it?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

PS: On keeping the field type string, free text search doesn't fetch proper results. On keeping the field type text, facet shows truncated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to implement the "copyField" approach, but I found another easy way to do this. In solr.impex, I had already added my new field manufacturerNameFacet of type string, but there is a parameter "fieldValueProvider" and "valueProviderParameter". I provided these values as "springELValueProvider" and the field I wanted to use for search and facet "manufacturerName". After a solr full indexing, it worked like a charm. No other setting was required. The search and facet both were working as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Using a copyField instruction is the way to go, but that require you to define an alternative field - meaning you have one field with the type `text` and the associated tokenization, and one field of the type `string` which isn't processed in any way. There is no way in Solr to combine these in a single field that I know of.

You'll then use the name of the string field to generate the facets, while you use the other field when you're querying.

```
<copyField source="text_search_field" dest="string_facet_field" />
```

You'll then have to refer to the name `string_facet_field` when you're filtering or faceting on the field. You'll want to filter against the facet field after the user selects a facet, since you otherwise would end up with documents from other facets possibly leaking into your document result set (for example if the facet was "Foo Bar", you'd suddenly get documents that had "Baz Foo Bar Spam" as the facet, since both words are present in the search string.

Comment: I'm really a novice at this. I added an extra field "manufacturerNameFacet" in solr.impex. Then I defined the field in solr's schema.xml and used copyField as you suggested. But on solr indexing from HMC, I'm getting an error "[solr indexer thread] ERROR solrIndexThreadLogger - cannot find attribute manufacturerNameFacet ". I also tried adding a dynamic field instead of field but same error. What am I missing? Any idea. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Hybris, but from your description I think I'd drop defining it in solr.impex - you don't have the new field in Hybris, just in Solr.